# Navigation bar is empty, created from storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

This is my story board:

[image]

Whenever I jump to a view controller embedded in navigation controller, the navigation bar is shown but empty, why?

The sequence I created it is:

1. connect buttons with destination view controllers
2. embed destination view controllers in navigation view controller

And the segue I use is present modally - cross dissolve.

Comment: What do you meant by empty? the nav bar doesnt show or what?

Comment: I don't know what do you want?

Comment: I want it to show the back button like usual @NguyenHoan

Comment: oh, embed  the first screen in Navigation bar.

Comment: @NguyenHoan the main view shouldn't have a navigation bar on top

Comment: you can hide navigationbar at the first screen. if you don't embed all screen in a stack - navigationcontroller , you can't back to previous view

Comment: @NguyenHoan no that is not a sulotion, it only put a navigation bar on the main screen and doesn't provide any navigation bar on the ones that need it.

Comment: Is your first viewController is pushed in a UINavigationController? If that's the case then you are nesting UINavigationController. The problem is only root UINavigationController's bar will be shown, any buttons added to other navigation bar wil be hidden under.

Comment: @Aks I don't quite get it, isn't it shown on my picture?

Comment: Ok. You are not nesting UINavigationController. But how are you adding UIBarButtonItems to navigationBar? As you are presenting your viewcontroller no button will be there by default. You have to use `navigationBar.righBarbutton` and similar for left.

Comment: Is your problem resolved by this?

Comment: @Aks you are right the modal transition doesn't show a back button, but I'm still trying to figure out a solution to put the `<` button on from the interface builder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123321/discussion-between-bright-future-and-aks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested different segue transition methods with test projects, the answer I got is: if you are transitioning by presenting it modally, you don't get the `back` button, you only get it by push.

Answer (score 0):

The First root controllers of a navigation controller won't have any Back button attached to its navigation bar. You should add an additional `View Controller` next to any root `View Controller` of `Navigation Controller` with `Push Segue` ( or `Show Segue` for newer IOS ) to navigate between them.

Comment: I have to use show modally for cross dissolve animation.